# Client to client connection via internet

Tags: perl, sockets, client, port

I have probably a very stupid question but just want to be sure of the answer. And please, sorry if I use any wrong expression here because I'm an absolute starter in network programming.

I recently started learning sockets and I decided to build a simple UNIX terminal chat. I decided to go with Perl into it, and made some simple client-server connections with message transferring in between them.

But then I got the idea to make a simple two way chat without the server, where one of the clients would act as a server instead. Well, that is the same thing as before on a local network, it's just a matter of perception :P

But what about on the internet?

Is there a way to implement a client-client ( and here by client I mean a personal machine really ) communication (where one of them is obviously acting as a server) without any need of the middleman as a host?

The main problem I see are the IP addresses, that is, the public IP addresses are those of routers and not of the machine itself. As I read on, I've came to the conclusion that it is impossible because of the low level implementation of internet's protocols and I've seen many implications that modern OSs wouldn't allow it for security reasons anyways.

Is there really no way to make a simple terminal chat work that way? For example that two different machines, behind different routers, run two different Perl scripts (one for the server and one for the client), and exchange information like on a typical client-server connection?

**Update:**

Ok, as stevieb mentioned that I should have a code example, here is the part in my Perl script that makes the server socket:

```
use IO::Socket;
use IO::Socket::INET;

my $reciever = new IO::Socket::INET ( 
    LocalHost => 'localhost',
    LocalPort => '9000',
    Proto => 'tcp', 
    Listen => 1, 
    Reuse => 1,
 ); die "Could not create socket: $!\n" unless $reciever;
```

This part works fine for a localhost server setup.

So lets say that my public IP adress is  11.1.11.111.

If I simply change the 5th line to:

```
LocalHost => '11.1.11.111.',
```

it throws:

```
Could not create socket: The requested address is not valid in its context.
```

What else am I missing and what would be the right way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: please show us the code you've got and ask questions related to the problems you're having with it, as with no code, this question is pretty off-topic (asking for recommendations, not code questions), and it may get closed.

Comment: A client can be both the server and the client. As long as one end accepts the request of the other, everything will be fine. Your biggest problem will be Network Address Translation (NAT) on the gateways that connect you to the Internet (your "router"). The end that receives the initial request will have to have "Port Forwarding" turned on to point to the IP and port of the device that will be listening for incoming connection requests, then you tell the client to connect to the 'server' at X port on the public IP address (the one on the outside of the gateway ("router")).